# Load nested models in a form containing a combo multiSelect=true in ExtJS 4.1.1

Tags: model, combobox, nested, extjs4.1, multi-select

Here is a shortened version of my code :

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Folder', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'name']
});

Ext.define('MyApp.model.User', {
    ...,
    hasMany: { model: 'Folder', name: 'folders' }
});

var form = Ext.widget('form', {
    ...,
    items: {
        xtype: 'combo',
        name: 'folders',
        multiSelect: true,
        valueField: 'id',
        displayField: 'name',
        queryMode: 'local',
        store: 'Folders'
    }
});

User.load(1, {
    success: function (user) {
        form.loadRecord(user);
    }
});
```

The data loaded by the User model :

```
{
    ...,
    folders: [
        { id: 1, name: 'folder 1' },
        { id: 2, name: 'folder 2' }
    ]
}
```

Assuming that everything (User model and store) loads successfully, and that the store contains folders 1, 2, N, I want the combo to select the values passed to the `loadRecord` method (folders 1 and 2), but the field stays empty. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution just after posting this question. However, I guess this must not be part of the "best practices", so, waiting for a better one, here is a good alternative :

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.User', {
    ...,
    hasMany: { model: 'Folder', name: 'folders' },
    fields: [..., {
        name: 'folders',
        convert: function (folders) {
            return Ext.Array.map(folders, function (folder) {
                return folder.id;
            });
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: Anybody find better solution ?